# Ignore formula if cell is blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm attempting to create a formula that essentially counts the days between today's date and the date entered in a cell.  So far I believe it works. See below:

```
=DATEDIF(H3, Today(), "D")
```

My dates are entered into column H and the formula is in column I.

My issue is if no date is entered it results with "`43201`". I would like it to stay blank or I'd settle with a dash or something.  Right now I applied conditional formatting to turn the cell black if it contains 43201..not an ideal solution.

I've looked and tried a few formulas but none seem to work with Google Sheets.

Answer (score 10):

The formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H3), "", DATEDIF(H3, Today(), "D"))
```

puts the empty string if H3 is blank. This is probably enough for your purpose.

Technically, the real *blank* output would be achieved with

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H3), , DATEDIF(H3, Today(), "D"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(H3:H);
 DATEDIF(H3:H; TODAY(); "D"); )); )
```

[image: 9]